# JMeter Regular Expression extractor one to one mapping

Tags: jmeter

I have an application where 100 devices are shown on home page. Each device has a separate device ID. Which I am extracting using JMeter Regular Expression extractor.

My scenario is if

User1 logs in then it should click on Device1.
User2 logs in then it should click on Device2.
User100 logs in then it should click on Device100.

In above case what should be the 'Match No' in JMeter Regular Expression extractor.

If am putting `0` its taking random device number for each user, where duplicate may happen.
If am putting `1` its taking Device1 for all users.

Please let me know how can I handel this one to one mapping in JMeter Regular Expression extractor.

Answer (score 0):

In a CSV define all the variables like UserName,Pwd,DeviceIDs. This will work as a one to one mapping.

In "user properties" add **sample_variables=UserName,Pwd,DeviceIDs** and save and restart jmeter.

Once it is done, in test plan use 100 Vuser and 1 loop. Now, all 100 mapping will be assign to 100 vuser and will be executed once. Also, in csv data set config, mark **Recycle on EOF** as False and "**Stop thread on EOF**" as True.

Comment: Hi Sunny,

Try to call the Device ID from CSV file. Here I am facing an issue that some of the request are failing & some of them are passing.

Please help me what could be the reason.

will you please let me know in berif , that how can I perform this from regular expression.

Comment: Hi Chittan, What I thought is not working in regular expression. Need to find something else. For CSV, check which request are failing and why? Are they the same requests that are failing again and again or Is it because of duplicate device id..